# PHP: How to convert some characters to emoji from string

Tags: php

I have chat application and I want to add function **which will find some characters form message string and converts it as emoji to save in database**.

My code is below:

```php
$list = array(
    '<3'        => '❤️',
    ':D'        => '',
    ':/'        => '',
    ':*'        => '',
    ':('        => '',
);

$string = ":DD I don't know how to fix this issue :D <3";        // message example
$array = explode(' ', $string);      // I am trying to explode message into array and then compare

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($list as $emoji => $emojied) {
        if(strpos($value, $emoji) !== false) {
            echo $emojied . '<br>';
        } else {
            echo $value;
        }
    }
}
```

But this does not work **correctly**

output is following:

> :DD
>
> :*DD:DD:DDIIIIIdon'tdon'tdon'tdon'tdon'tknowknowknowknowknowhowhowhowhowhowtototototofixfixfixfixfixthisthisthisthisthisissueissueissueissueissue:D
>   :D:D:D❤️ <3<3<3<3*

It should be:

> :DD I don't know how to fix this issue  ❤️**

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: what did you do to debug ? It seems this is easy stuff, replacing some text by some other text, it shouldn't be a big problem, maybe there's a typo somewhere, something you can (and should) try to find on your own first. You have to show us you have done something to resolve your issue. You may have to do some `print_r` stuff in your `foreach` loop to see step by step what's wrong

Answer (score 1):

You can do this much more simply using str_replace and array arguments:

```
<?php


$list = array(
    '<3'        => '❤️',
    ':D'        => '',
    ':/'        => '',
    ':*'        => '',
    ':('        => '',
);

$string = ":DD I don't know how to fix this issue :D <3";        // message example

$keys = array_keys($list);
$values = array_values($list);

$output = str_replace($keys, $values, $string);

print $output;
```

Generates the output:

```
D I don't know how to fix this issue  ❤️
```

Comment: Thank you!! you saved me

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use the `strtr` function, which is more suitable for this scenario, example:

```
<?php

$string = ":DD I don't know how to fix this issue :D <3";        // message example

$list = array(
    '<3' => '❤️',
    ':D' => '',
    ':/' => '',
    ':*' => '',
    ':(' => '',
);

print strtr($string, $list);
```

output:

```
D I don't know how to fix this issue  ❤️
```

Comment: Thanks sir for your help